# Setting DKIM and SPF records for client domains

Tags: email, domain, email-server, spam, dkim

I have created an email server that is capable of handling mail for multiple websites. e.g. tom@website1.com, tom@website2.com etc. The emails are sending and receiving fine, but the spam score is terrible.

All of the websites hosted have MX records pointing to mail1.mysite.com. I have DKIM setup for mysite.com and spf setup too. Emails sent from mysite.com get a perfect spam free score, but those sent from other domains get sent straight to spam.

Is there a way for me to apply DKIM, reverse dns and SPF to domains that are using my mail1.mysite.com without having to loginto their DNS records and modify them?

Comment: So you want to use three DNS-based techniques without using DNS?

Comment: when google hosts domain specific email how do they do it? they dont go around asking for godaddy passwords

Comment: Google actually has the same "problem". So they tell customers to add those DNS records themselves: [SPF](https://support.google.com/a/answer/178723?hl=en) and [DKIM](https://support.google.com/a/answer/174124?hl=en).

Comment: damn it. this is going to be difficult to explain to people who dont even know who they registered their domain with. can anything be done for reverse dns?

Comment: Reverse DNS for the mailserver's IP should be mail1.mysite.com. That is all you can do.

Answer (score 0):

No. The DKIM and SPF records must be added to the domain's DNS records by the domain owner or their authorized agent using the domain's authoritative name server.